# Chrome PHP Set Cookie bug?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

I've run into a funny little problem an I have no  idea what to do. I'm running this code:

index.php: (wrapped in a ob_start() to buffer everything so the header can be set before anything is outputted)

```
$session = new Sessions();
$session->create('user');
$session->create('system');
$session->create('data');
```

Part of the session class:

```
public function create($session){
    $cookie_name = $this->get_cookie_name($session);
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

        if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_write_close();
            session_unset();
        }

        session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', COOKIE_URL);
        session_save_path(TEMP . 'sessions');
        session_name($cookie_name);

        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id();

        $session_id = session_id();
        $_SESSION['PHP_SESSION_NAME'] = $session;
        session_write_close();
        session_unset();

        echo '$cookie_name: ' . $cookie_name . '<br>';
        echo 'SESSION_ID: ' . $session_id  . '<br>';
    }
}
```

the headers that are sent from php:

```
Set-Cookie:ses_user=7o5uoqdn95a3kt7k6argb2rab7dar9oe94v96rqqdpqk47g7m00g80m2j3fbcs50r1b2b02q4tsn7p98jq9cf6lq1uq1bv717s74p02; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ses_system=ac2f362l3fmui0uon31hu1h64k4sa0mlj9g3kq3c7bd7tsnpgbon7fehqqfiqf5sj50jajqqd4km7l2hal6vfd6okg7lfohg1tt66g2; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ses_system=u84aiiun9ji8t8m0akkv0dpdmu27gcan4rik0klkg163j43ii849elde3alubj6bsljai8vtkptt18oplgo3s9421hk50dr3c4s27t1; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ses_data=u84aiiun9ji8t8m0akkv0dpdmu27gcan4rik0klkg163j43ii849elde3alubj6bsljai8vtkptt18oplgo3s9421hk50dr3c4s27t1; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ses_data=vn7k19iu91sq9mf3tnrrurqddhluk3pqsi5p8rs10unhnk8rus9702uuoml663l5nnhmj084l6t6cve78ru5th2jqk3mub8f6tei6h1; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ses_user=ac2f362l3fmui0uon31hu1h64k4sa0mlj9g3kq3c7bd7tsnpgbon7fehqqfiqf5sj50jajqqd4km7l2hal6vfd6okg7lfohg1tt66g2; path=/; domain=.certastic.com; HttpOnly
```

It worked at first, I kept deleting the cookies to test a few things. After a while it stopped working, **the cookies will not set**, if I change the name of the the session it will work. It also works fine in Firefox. Anyone know what I can do to get this working?

Comment: Having multiple sessions doesn't make a lot of sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: There is a reason I want to use diffrent sessions. I want to be able to destroy a session but still have the some data saved of the user. I know it is possible to use multiple sessions.